# Does $|X_{n}|^{r}$ converge to $|X|^{r}$ in probability imply $X_{n}$ converge to $X$ in probability?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $X_{n}, n\geq 1$, $X$ be real-valued random variables and $r>0$. Then $|X_{n}|^{r}$ converge to $|X|^{r}$ in probability imply $X_{n}$ converge to $X$ in probability.

Is the above statement correct?

I understand the reverse direction is correct but I don't know whether this statement is correct.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: No. Suppose $X_n = -1$, all $n$. $X = 1$.